# Oracle to T-SQL conversion. How can I make this work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

Having trouble converting Oracle syntax to T-SQL. Trying to convert the following statement:

```
SELECT ORIG.*
,V.COUNTRY_COMMON_NAME
FROM 
(SELECT O.*
  ,LC.LOCAL_COUNCIL
  ,LC.REGIONAL_COUNCIL
FROM ES_W_ORG_DIM_INIT O
LEFT JOIN ES_W_ORG_DIM_INIT CNTR ON (O.RSC_CNTR_ORG_ID = CNTR.ORG_ID)
LEFT JOIN ES_W_LCL_CNCL_BASE LC ON (TO_CHAR(O.STK_DIST_UNIT_NUMBER) = 
TRIM(LC.UNITNUMBER))
WHERE O.ORG_TYPE_ID IN (7,8)
UNION
SELECT O.*
  ,LC.LOCAL_COUNCIL
  ,LC.REGIONAL_COUNCIL
FROM ES_W_ORG_DIM_INIT O
LEFT JOIN ES_W_ORG_DIM_INIT CNTR ON (O.RSC_CNTR_ORG_ID = CNTR.ORG_ID)
LEFT JOIN ES_W_LCL_CNCL_BASE LC ON (TO_CHAR(O.UNIT_NUMBER) = 
TRIM(LC.UNITNUMBER))
WHERE O.ORG_TYPE_ID IN (5,6)
UNION
SELECT O.*
  ,NULL AS LOCAL_COUNTCIL
  ,NULL AS REGIONAL_COUNCIL
FROM ES_W_ORG_DIM_INIT O
WHERE O.ORG_TYPE_ID IN (60,61)
) ORIG
LEFT JOIN DW_ERSDB_ORG_ADDR_VW V ON (ORIG.ORG_ID = V.ORG_ID AND 
V.ORG_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID = 1)
```

Attempted conversion:

```
WITH ORIG AS(
SELECT O.*
  ,LC.LOCAL_COUNCIL
  ,LC.REGIONAL_COUNCIL
FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_ORG_DIM O
LEFT JOIN DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_ORG_DIM CNTR ON (O.RSC_CNTR_ORG_ID = CNTR.ORG_ID)
LEFT JOIN DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_W_LCL_CNCL_BASE LC ON (CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
O.STK_DIST_UNIT_NUMBER) = RTRIM(LTRIM(LC.UNITNUMBER)))
WHERE O.ORG_TYPE_ID IN (7,8)
UNION
(SELECT O.*
  ,LC.LOCAL_COUNCIL
  ,LC.REGIONAL_COUNCIL
FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_ORG_DIM O
LEFT JOIN DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_ORG_DIM CNTR ON (O.RSC_CNTR_ORG_ID = CNTR.ORG_ID)
LEFT JOIN DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_W_LCL_CNCL_BASE LC ON (CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
O.UNIT_NUMBER) = RTRIM(LTRIM(LC.UNITNUMBER)))
WHERE O.ORG_TYPE_ID IN (5,6)
UNION
SELECT O.*
  ,NULL AS LOCAL_COUNCIL
  ,NULL AS REGIONAL_COUNCIL
FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_ORG_DIM O
WHERE O.ORG_TYPE_ID IN (60,61)
))
SELECT ORIG.*, V.COUNTRY_COMMON_NAME
FROM ORIG
LEFT JOIN DSS_ERS_STAGE.DW_ERSDB_ORG_ADDR_VW V ON (ORIG.ORG_ID = V.ORG_ID 
AND 
V.ORG_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID = 1)
```

*Just a note that the schemas specified are required in the target database

SQL Server error:

```
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'LOCAL_COUNCIL' was specified multiple times for 'ORIG'.
```

Any ideas on how I can engineer this to make it work in SQL Server?

Comment: The error returned is because your query contains the column LOCAL_COUNCIL multiple times. This is usual when you use the * in your query. I would replace it by the columns you need in your program. Take a look on O.* and you will see that that column exists there also.

Comment: Also when you specify a varchar you should ALWAYS specify the size.https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jamie mentioned this in a comment but I'll try to explain in a bit more detail. For purposes of illustration, suppose I have the following two very simple tables.

```
create table CouncilA (LOCAL_COUNCIL int);
create table CouncilB (LOCAL_COUNCIL int);

insert CouncilA values (1);
insert CouncilB values (1);
```

SQL Server does allow you to query a result set that has non-unique column names. For instance, the following is legal:

```
select *
from
    CouncilA A
    inner join CouncilB B on A.LOCAL_COUNCIL = B.LOCAL_COUNCIL;
```

It produces the following result set:

```
LOCAL_COUNCIL   LOCAL_COUNCIL
1               1
```

However, the [documentation for common table expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) explicitly states:

> Duplicate names within a single CTE definition are not allowed.

So if I try to wrap my earlier query like this, as you've done in your attempted conversion:

```
with CTE as
(
    select *
    from
        CouncilA A
        inner join CouncilB B on A.LOCAL_COUNCIL = B.LOCAL_COUNCIL
)
select * from CTE;
```

Then I get the error message that you're seeing:

```
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The column 'LOCAL_COUNCIL' was specified multiple times for 'CTE'.
```

Incidentally, the same is true for a sub-`SELECT`:

```
select * from
(
    select *
    from
        CouncilA A
        inner join CouncilB B on A.LOCAL_COUNCIL = B.LOCAL_COUNCIL
) X;
```

Result:

```
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
The column 'LOCAL_COUNCIL' was specified multiple times for 'X'.
```

The error message you see refers to `ORIG`, which is the name of your CTE, so the definition of that CTE has multiple columns called `LOCAL_COUNCIL`, which presumably means that your `ES_W_ORG_DIM_INIT` table has a column called `LOCAL_COUNCIL`. Make sure your column names are unique within your CTE and you should be okay.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.